# Bundling react components based on per-component permission control before they are transpiled and shipped to client

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asp.net-core, webpack

1. I am developing an involved web app with asp.net core.
2. I am developing React components, writing all of my components with ES and JSX syntax.
3. I run webpack to transpile all of my code (so now I have pre-transpiled files ready to be served)
4. When a request comes in, I just serve my pre-transpiled bundles.

I wanted to have a way of only bundling and sending user-specific components (based on a list of features they have access to) to the client.

The only way I could figure doing this is to do "on-the-fly permission-controlled component bundling combined with on-the-fly jsx compilation" to serve my components.

I gather that webpack shouldn't be used as an on-the-fly bundler like this, so that is out of the picture...

**Partial scrappy solution I came up with:**

Using no importing or export mechanism in my js, I use Razor to cycle through my feature list, adding the appropriate (mostly modular) components in what I call "Dependency First Order" to the page, and at the end of each components' code, I write

> class ComponentA extends React.Component  { //Component Code Here }
>
> window.ComponentA = ComponentA;

So all components are global and can be rendered.
This way, I am able to select what Components get sent to the client with Razor.
NOW, remember when I said "mostly modular"? Well if I am rendering a component within another component that the user doesn't have access to, this partial solution would leave the render statement embedded in main component that is rendering the sub-component itself, without the component code it's supposed to render actually being there. This being a dirty partial solution, I would just suppress the error if the component was non-existent and move on.

**Bottom line** is I am having a real difficult time making my react components 100% modular and being able to control the granularity of my 'component dependencies' so that no code is on the client that a user shouldn't have access to.

**Ridiculous solution someone offered me:**

It is also certainly out of the question that I would generate a set of bundles for every user and whenever an admin changes what a user has access to, I would re-render that bundle with webpack. (especially since I am dealing with thousands of users here).
As I am writing all of this, the more and more I feel like I am just being a perfectionist and should just go with the above paragraph.

**The solution I should probably go with:**

There is the ideology out there to just send all of your js to the browser and then selectively render them based on the permission of the user. Any security loopholes here would just be handled by server-side access control to lock down endpoints if a specific user did try to forge requests to parts of the application they don't have access to (which would be implemented regardless).

I am under the gun here and feel like I am overthinking most of this. I would be greatly appreciative of any feedback. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to ship permission based JS bundle to client. You can leverage `webpack` dynamic import logic to load only required features JS bundles.

You need to create directory structure based on features and load them based on user permissions. Basically what `webpack` does is, it creates separate bundle for each feature and load it via dynamic import when requested.

Solution here

[image: Edit 91zqvryz6o]

**Note:** You might not see lazy bundles in codesandbox.io network panel, but, you can download project and run server locally to see bundles being lazy loaded.

Comment: Referencing this:  `const allowedFeatures = features.slice(0, 2);` how would I go about inserting it into the js file itself since it is dynamic?

Comment: You can make a API call, get allowed features list and store in `allowedFeatures` state variable and load bundles using it. Or you can send user permission metadata in a JS variable in landing HTML, read it in your component and use it.

Comment: And this is all on the server side? I'm sorry I guess I'm missing something here. I am not necessarily rendering the components themselves server side

Comment: **Server:** You basically generate bundles for all features during build time(`webpack` traverses `./features-index/` folder for JS files and creates a bundle for each of them). 
**Client:** You fetch user permission config from server, loop through it, pass feature names to dynamic import function. `webpack` loads that feature JS bundle automatically which was created in server and renders it. So, basically you are only loading JS bundles of features to which user has access to.

Read more about dynamic import here - https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#dynamic-imports

Comment: So let me see if I can get this right: all of the component code will be sent to the client, but whether or not it is rendered is based looping through the config file for permission control.

Comment: all of the component code won't be sent to the client by default. client can load what component code it wants based on permission control. Can you download project and run server locally, change and check `allowedFeatures` array to see different bundles being lazy loaded(check network panel) every time you make the change to  `allowedFeatures`.

Comment: Ah. I am comprehending now. This solution works perfectly with what I am trying to achieve. Thank you for your extended discussion.

Comment: Nice that it helped. Cheers!